# Book for understanding Internet Telephony?

Tags: sip, telephony

I'm a developer, system/network administrator, and I'm very familiar in setting up internet services such as Apache, BIND, SSH, etc. but what I'm entirely new to is telephony. Is there a book or guide available somewhere to help me understand from the ground up how internet telephony works? I'd like to know how I could write service stacks on top of IP telephony for various uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet the user manual for Asterisk would be a good source, and might also point you to more generic resources.

Comment: Reading "[Asterisk: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517342/)" right now, extremely helpful.